# IronPython Crash NOT for Python 2.7 and 3.3

Tags: python, python-2.7, ironpython

I have no idea why the Ironpython crash after executing DLL but NOT python 2.7 and 3.3

My code as below

```
import ctypes
import time
DLLHANDLE=ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\INSTRDLL\\builds\\DCSOURCEDLL\\B2902A.dll")
INPUTSCRIPT="SYSTEM{DCSOURCE1|INIT}"
INPUTVOLTAGE=0.0
SOURCEHANDLE=DLLHANDLE.DCSOURCE(c_INPUTSCRIPT,c_INPUTVOLTAGE)
time.sleep(1)
```

Basically, The DLL is calling instrument to perform initialization once `INPUTSCRIPT` is issued.

I have attached the Crash screenshot. Please help...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`ctypes`, in general, is a whole pile of whatever the opposite of fun is. With normal Python, it's like coding in C - watch your pointers, data types, etc. - but at least CPython is relatively close to C and it works acceptably (it also the advantage of being much more widely used).

In IronPython, it's that, plus the CLR has to intermediate everything - it uses the .NET marshaling APIs, and also generates P/Invoke declarations at runtime. The code to do this is rather complicated and has known bugs - dealing with raw memory is not what .NET is designed to do!

One area of concern is that IronPython uses Unicode strings, while you don't specify what type the `DCSOURCE` function takes (wide/Unicode/`wchar_t*` or narrow/ANSI/`char*`). Without knowing the signature of the C function it's hard to say. I also don't remember what IronPython ctypes assumes and converts to by default.